# Running a database query before every route runs

Tags: php, slim, idiorm

So I am using Slim Framework, idiorm and twig to build an application and have a separate template file for my menu which is included on every page. The menu has a select menu that is generated from a database query and so needs to be included on every route. How can I have this query call on every route without actually declaring it on every route.

Can I use the hook system. I am not sure how to tackle this.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Can you close the question or haven't you found the answer yet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right, you could use the hook with slim.before.router like:

```
$app->hook('slim.before.router', function() use($app) {
    $svc = $app->menuService; // do you use slim ioc? 
    $menu = $svc->getMenu(); // inject the menu to the app
    $app->menu = $menu;
});
```

You could also use a Middleware

```
class MyMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware
{
    public function call()
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'username', 'password');
        $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, key, value FROM menu_items");
        $menu = $q->fetch();
        $this->app->menu = $menu; 
        $this->next->call();
    }
}
```

How frequently the menu changes? In my opinion if not more than twice per day and those are just a few values to fill a select element, you would be better to have it on a resource (like a json object) and save it directly.

Otherwise i would rather call that query everytime the first query in that session is executed or have it on a in memory database like redis.

Comment: Hey thanks. Not using slim ioc. Is it still possible. It is all pretty new to me. Any other advice would be awesome.

Comment: What's your database? I've updated the example for a case where you would retrieving the menu from a mysql database.

Comment: I cant edit the above comment but are you also asking help to bring the menu data to your html? If so, are you passing any model to the view? You can pass the menu from there and have a helper to fetch models with the same property or easier, just save the menu in a session and use it in the views. (i'm sorry but i don't know how new you are to progamming to be sure if is this what you're asking)